# Memory limits in webassembly

Tags: memory, browser, webassembly

What will be the policy of memory allocation limits for webassembly programs?

Will the current (hard) javascript engine memory limits be inherited? 
E.g. will be possible to write real applications that needs more than a few hundred of megs of memory?

Current browser policies on memory allocation on javascript pose hard constraints to what is actually doable in a browser. 
Speed is no more a problem with emscripten/asm.js and jit compiling, but the memory constraints make hard or impossible to build any serious application in a browser.

See for example http://www.meshlabjs.net, the run-in-browser version of the MeshLab mesh processing system. With respect to the desktop application the main limit is that, in the javascript based version, large 3D models cannot be loaded  for the intrinsic limits on allocation imposed by the js engine of the browsers.

Comment: More recent, related: [Memory limits in Pyodide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75559641/967621)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I summarize a bit the above answers, the comments and a bit more of googling done around; there are two issues that prevent using WebAssembly for being used projects that require a significant amount of memory:

- current WebAssembly implementations follow a 32bit addressing space model, so no hope of using more than 4gb of mem until **wasm64** is out ([proposal overview](https://github.com/WebAssembly/memory64/blob/master/proposals/memory64/Overview.md)).
- browsers arbitrarily decide what is the amount of memory given to a page. This is (mostly) for security reason because people love to think to web pages as something more "safe" than desktop applications.

Hopefully both issues can be solved. I hope that browsers will expose those limits in a explicit way; just like when a page request to use your camera it is notified, you should simply notify the user that a page want a ton of memory and block it until you answer.

Comment: What gives the idea that you can't write serious software in 32 bit? Most desktop software these days still runs in 32 bit, let alone mobile.

Comment: With 'serious' I mean 'requiring a significant amount of memory'. Sorry for not being sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 19):

WebAssembly has a [`WebAssembly.Memory`](http://webassembly.org/docs/js/#webassemblymemory-constructor) object and the binary has a [memory section](http://webassembly.org/docs/binary-encoding/#memory-section). Through these, a developer provides educated guesses about minimum and maximum memory usage, the VM then allocates at least the minimum (or fails). A developer can then, at runtime, ask for more through [`grow_memory`](http://webassembly.org/docs/semantics/#resizing) which tools like Emscripten will use under the hood of `malloc` (it's somewhat similar to `sbrk`).

For asm.js it was difficult to know how the `ArrayBuffer` was going to be used, and on some 32-bit platforms you often ran into process fragmentation which made it hard to allocate enough contiguous space in the process' virtual memory (the `ArrayBuffer` **must** be contiguous in the browser process' virtual address space, otherwise you'd have a huge perf hit). You'd try to allocate 256MiB and sometimes hard-fail. This got extremely difficult if the browser wasn't multi-process, because all the other tabs are competing for 32 bits of virtual address space. Browsers [were a bit silly a few years ago, they got better](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=394591), but 32 bits ain't much to go around.

WebAssembly is backed by `WebAssembly.Memory` which is a special type of `ArrayBuffer`. This means that a WebAssembly implementation can be clever about that `ArrayBuffer`. On 32-bit there's not much to do: if you run out of contiguous address space then the VM can't do much. But on 64-bit platforms there's plenty of address space. The browser implementation can choose to prevent you from creating too many `WebAssembly.Memory` instances (allocating virtual memory is *almost* free, but not quite), but you should be able to get a few 4GiB allocations. Note that the browser will only allocate that space virtually, and commit physical addresses for the minimum number of pages you said you need. Afterwards it'll only allocate physically when you use `grow_memory`. That could fail (physical memory is about as abundant as the amount of RAM, give or take swap space), but it's *much* more predictable.

An implementation can pull a similar trick on 32-bit platforms (over-commit but keep `PROT_NONE` and not physically allocated), assuming fragmentation allows, but that's up to the implementation and how it think this affects ASLR. Realistically it's hard to find memory when there's not much to go around, but virtually and physically.

WebAssembly is currently specified as an ILP32 process: pointers are 32 bits. You're therefore hard-limited to 4GiB. We may add [wasm64](https://github.com/WebAssembly/memory64/blob/master/proposals/memory64/Overview.md) in the future.

Comment: Actually, I think the `WebAssembly.Memory` API has nothing to do with it. It's rather the fact that a Wasm module can define its own memory, unlike asm.js, where it always was an import from JS, so the engine had no way of distinguishing the use case.

Comment: That said, the memory restrictions in JS engines are mostly not due to hardware or address space limitations, but to prevent web pages from killing the machine with OOM, which is easy on some OSes. That would apply to Wasm as well. I'm not sure if we have settled on anything in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Relevant proposals ([see their current stages here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals)):

### Multiple Memories

> This proposal adds the ability to use multiple memories within a single Wasm module. In the current version of Wasm, an application can already create multiple memories, but only by splitting things up into multiple modules. A single module or function cannot refer to multiple memories at the same time. Consequently, it is not possible to e.g. efficiently transfer data from one memory to another, since that necessarily involves an individual function call into a different module per value.

https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-memory/blob/master/proposals/multi-memory/Overview.md

### Memory64

> This page describes a proposal to support linear memory of sizes larger than 2^32 bits. It provides no new instructions, but instead extends the currently existing instructions to allow 64-bit indexes.

> WebAssembly linear memory objects have sizes measured in pages. Each page is 65536 (2^16) bytes. In WebAssembly version 1, a linear memory can have at most 65536 pages, for a total of 2^32 bytes (4 gibibytes). In addition to this page limit, all memory instructions currently use the i32 type as a memory index. This means they can address at most 2^32 bytes as well.

https://github.com/WebAssembly/memory64/blob/master/proposals/memory64/Overview.md